# IIS excutable permissions to convert doc to pdf?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have an asp.net application which converts the uploaded ms doc to pdf using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass.It works fine in my local machine ,but it is not working on deployed IIS server.Are there any executable permissions is required to get the output.

Error is:
 Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005.

my code as follows:

```
public class Word2Pdf
{
    private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass MSWordDoc;
    object UnknownType = Type.Missing;
    public string Word2PdfCOnversion(object InputLocation, object OutputLocation)
    {
        string result;
        try
        {
            //if (MSWordDoc == null) 
            MSWordDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
            MSWordDoc.Visible = false;
            MSWordDoc.Documents.Open(ref InputLocation,    //Input File Name Location
                ref UnknownType,    // Conversion Conformation
                ref UnknownType,    // Set ReadOnly Property
                ref UnknownType,    // Add to the Recent Files
                ref UnknownType,    // Document Password Setting
                ref UnknownType,    // Password Templete
                ref UnknownType,    // Revert
                ref UnknownType,    // Write Password to Document
                ref UnknownType,    // Write Password Template
                ref UnknownType,    // File Format
                ref UnknownType,    // Encoding File
                ref UnknownType,    // Visibility
                ref UnknownType,    // To Open or Repair
                ref UnknownType,    // Document Direction
                ref UnknownType,    // Encoding Dialog
                ref UnknownType);   // XML Text Transform
            MSWordDoc.Application.Visible = false;  // To Invisible the Word Document
            MSWordDoc.WindowState = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;    // Minimize the Opened Word File.
            object SavePDFFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
            MSWordDoc.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ref OutputLocation, //Output File Location
            ref SavePDFFormat,    // File Format
            ref UnknownType,    // Comment to PDF File
            ref UnknownType,    // Password
            ref UnknownType,    // Add to Recent File
            ref UnknownType,    // Write Password
            ref UnknownType,    // ReadOnly Propert
            ref UnknownType,    // Original Font Embeding
            ref UnknownType,    // Save Picture
            ref UnknownType,    // Saving Form Datas
            ref UnknownType,    // Save as AOVE Letter
            ref UnknownType,    // Encoding
            ref UnknownType,    // Inserting Line Breakes
            ref UnknownType,    // Allow Substitution
            ref UnknownType,    // Line Ending
            ref UnknownType);   // Add BiDi Marks
            result = "Success";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = "Error";
        }
        finally
        {
            if (MSWordDoc == null) { }
            else { MSWordDoc.Documents.Close(ref UnknownType, ref UnknownType, ref UnknownType); }
            MSWordDoc.Quit(ref UnknownType, ref UnknownType, ref UnknownType);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the Com Compenent you are using is registered on the Server?

Comment: If you're using a recent version of .Net, you don't need all the `ref UnknownType` parameters.  .Net 3.5 and later allowed these parameters to be optional and if omitted defaulted to `Type.Missing`.  Might make to code shorter and easier to scan... YMMV

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup permissions for the COM components you want to use.  On the server, run the `dcomcnfg` utility.

Under "Component Services\Computers\My Computer\DCOM Config" locate the CLSID's for the word components you require.  (Helpfully, I've seen some machines list them as guids i.e. `{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` and other machines have the office components listed via name).

You need to right click on the CLSID and select properties, alter the "Launch and Activation Permissions", the "Access Permissions" and the "Identity" setting to allow the website app pool account the necessarily rights to automate Word.

Incidentally, you might need more CLSID's than the one you've mentioned.  When I worked on a project that converted doc and/or html to PDF using word, we had to add the CLSID of Word and for several Word Picture types too.

From memory the CLSID's were:
 `{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`
 `{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-0000000000FE}`
 `{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-0000000000FF}`

Hopefully that should point you in the right direction.